# Ihnen hat das nicht gefallen. vs: Sie ließen sich das nicht gefallen

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference in the meaning between the 2 expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are simply stumbling over the verb **gefallen**, which has an oddly irregular past participle: *gefallen*. Same as the infinitive and same as the past participle of the verb *fallen*.

> Ihnen hat das nicht gefallen.

That's simply the *Perfekt* of

> Ihnen gefällt das nicht.

*They don't like that.*

---

In contrary, the following sentence isn't *Perfekt*, but *Präteritum*:

> Sie ließen sich das nicht gefallen. *(Präteritum)*
>
> Sie haben sich das nicht gefallen lassen. *(Perfekt)*

And **gefallen** isn't a past participle here but the **infinitive**. How do you tell? Well, modal verbs as *lassen* always take the infinitive:

> Sie lassen sich nicht hängen.

The meaning of the verb *gefallen* is *to like* and the phrase *sich etwas gefallen lassen* consequently means literally *to let yourself like it*, in reality *to tolerate*.

> Sie lassen sich das nicht gefallen.

*They don't tolerate that.*

Answer (score 0):

"Sich etwas gefallen lassen" referrs to accepting something, generally speaking, when you negate it ("Sich etwas nicht gefallen lassen"), that referrs to attempting to stop something/someone, usually the something negatively affecting the person in question.

"Etwas gefällt jemandem nicht" just means a person dislikes [event], there is no implied action taken.

Comment: You mean "to dislike" is a _stative_ verb, don't you?